Remove repeated speaker names from Zoom vtt
The VTT files generated by Zoom always repeat the speaker name for every new subtitle/caption line.
I want to create a transcript that only includes the first instance of the speaker name before switching to a different speaker.
It's easy enough to remove the timecodes, but it's tricky to find a way, at least in Word, to clean up the duplicate speaker names.
A VTT of speakers Y and Z with timecodes removed will look something like this:
Y: AAA

Y: BBB

Z: CCC

Z: DDD

Z: EEE

Y: FFF

Z: GGG

And I want the outcome to look like this:
Y: AAA BBB

Z: CCC DDD EEE

Y: FFF

Z: GGG

In Word, I can find
(Y:)(*)(Y:)
but I want the asterisk string of text to NOT include exactly "Z:" anywhere so that I can replace with
\1\2
